# Default FBSDKLoginBehavior.Native not working on iOS 9

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, ios9, fast-app-switching

I just upgraded my app to Xcode 7 / Swift 2.0 and I'm struggling with the Facebook Login via AppSwitch. I'm on the latest FBSDK (4.6) and did everything according to the [upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9). Still, on iOS9 the Facebook login happens via in-app browser, the appswitch doesn't work anymore. I also tried force setting the loginbehavior but without luck:

```
let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
manager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Native
manager.logInWithReadPermissions(facebookReadPermissions, fromViewController: nil, handler: { (loginResult, error) -> Void in
```

Is there anything I can do to make appswitch work again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that this is not an issue but the new desired behavior according to these posts from Facebook:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1636969533209725/?comment_id=1011596265571252

> This behavior is by design. In our latest iOS SDKs, the login behavior is now controlled on the server side in order to ensure the best user experience.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/?comment_id=1467419033584031

> Because of introduced changes in iOS 9, This new behavior avoids the user to be asked if they want to go and open the Facebook Application, accept the permissions/share/etc, and then ask once more if they want to switch back to your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1390559277910338/?comment_id=1661064587442645

> System authentication doesn't give people control over the information they share with apps. And in iOS 9, fast-app-switching to the Facebook native app results in additional dialogs ("ExampleApp would like to open Facebook") which appear twice - once on the way from ExampleApp to Facebook, and once again on the return journey. We believe the default SDK behavior in v4.6 on iOS 9 offers the best experience to people logging into your app with Facebook.

Comment: So why then is the following still included in the SDK -> loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Native.

Comment: it's used on iOS < 9

Answer (score 0):

You can patch FacebookSDK source code to use Fast App Switching.

The interesting part (for tag 4.6) is in file [`FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/ServerConfiguration/FBSDKServerConfigurationManager.m`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/fe777bd7a8b335c5780e2ee160d81719e132e76c#diff-90ec6eb3e850cae6d0f3da852f37d32cR72)

```
+ (FBSDKServerConfiguration *)_defaultServerConfigurationForAppID:(NSString *)appID
{
    …
    BOOL useNativeFlow = ![FBSDKInternalUtility isOSRunTimeVersionAtLeast:iOS9Version];
```

As you can see, it disables native flow on iOS9+.
Changing the line to something like `BOOL useNativeFlow = YES;` should work.

P.S. I didn't check this patch myself yet.

Comment: not working, but I think this will work. I am adding "fbapi" in URL Scheme